# Hypernym for webstore features?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Behold the following list:

- Special Offers
- Free Products
- New Arrivals
- Restocked Items
- Limited Stock

These are all... what? *Offers? Categories? Filters? Marketing Ploys?*

Comment: In what context?  Maybe they're all menu items.

Comment: From the context of a typical web store navigation menu. If this list were in the footer, for example, it would appear under its hypernym, next to another group of navigation options.

Comment: You called them *features* already!

Comment: Just label it "View..."

Comment: @Kris You're right, _features_ definitely applies, but everything on this list has an element of time-sensitivity that _features_ doesn't seem to address.

Comment: @Jim _View_ addresses this a bit by adding a verb to the equation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hot Links
- Offerings
- Hot Commodities
- Today's Specials
- Get 'em While They're Hot!

Answer (score 0):

If you need an attractive heading for the section on the webstore rather than the exact English word, you could use : "What's hot?"